# How will NASA perseverance re-enter the earth from Mars

Tags: mars, nasa

Perseverance has been in Mars since 2021, and I'm just wondering the mechanism through with it will return to earth.

Comment: It won’t. See https://xkcd.com/695

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* You might be thinking of the future [Mars sample return mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_sample-return_mission), where **the samples being collected by the Perseverance rover** will be collected, put into a small rrobotic rocket, launched to orbit, transferred to a waiting robotic spacecraft that will indeed return to Earth so that the Mars samples can be examined by scientists here on Earth. If that's what you are thinking of, I think you can go ahead and modify your question post (click edit) to clarify.

Comment: For more on that, see a related question in Space Exploration SE [What precautions are planned to prevent samples returned from Mars crashing and releasing organisms into Earth's environment?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45035/12102)

Comment: You may want to check Space Exploration SE.